# "One-sided form" of the "half-open range operator"

Tags: swift, range, operators

From **Basic Operators — The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)**;

> The **half-open range operator also has a one-sided form** that’s written
>   with only its **final value**. Just like when you include a value on both
>   sides, the **final value** isn’t part of the range. For example:

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]

// Prints "Anna" and "Alex".
for name in names[..<2] {
    print(name)
}
```

My question is; why can't we have this for the **first value** as well?

```
// The next three lines are all valid.
var a = 0...
var b = ...0
var c = ..<0

// But this line is not, compilation error...
var d = 0<..
```

Comment: There is no `<..` operator. You can use `var d = 1...` instead.

Comment: @MartinR wow i'm actually surprised that such a thing exists. What would be the use case for this? I just tried iterating it and it goes on an infinite run.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I am so stupid...

Comment: It's not even possible to define such operator :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator is not a right operator:

```
var d = 0<.. /// Swift doesn't have this operator
```

If you want that you need more then 0 then use below:

```
var d = 1...
var d = 2...
var d = 3...
```

For more detail, You can check this link: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know why Swift does not have this operator yet, or if it's being considered in a future update?